# How to make each image shareable to social media on a website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins, elementor

I'm creating a new website using Elementor and Wordpress wherein I need to add multiple GIFs and images that should be shareable across social media.

However the social icons in Elementor are meant to share the entire webpage. How do I add these social media buttons to each image and GIF.

**The final result should consist of an image/GIF which when hovered over shows social media icons which share ONLY that image/GIF on their personal social media.**

Please suggest Elementor friendly solutions

Answer (score 0):

There are ways of doing it, Creating a custom plugin with that functional **[Auto publish plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-media-auto-publish/)** on WordPress